# How to filter out rows with the same exact text from two different Columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

SQL beginner here.

I have two Columns of data that contain rows with the same exact text/value. Specifically, the beginning value(Column 1) and the end value(Column 2) are the same.

I want to filter them out and leave rows where the beginning value and the end value are different. What's the most efficient way to do it?

I only know the basic commands of SQL, I tried the distinct command but I don't think that is it. I have other columns that need to be included in the table.

Comment: `select * from your_table where col1 != col2`

Comment: Filtering of rows occurs through the **where** clause. In that clause you can compare the 2 columns via the "not equal" operator which is `<>` (or you can use `!=` if you prefer) e.g. `where col1 <> col2` . (*Please note that `select distinct` simply reduces a result down so that every row is unique. It isn't relevant to a comparison of 2 columns.*)